# Type mismatch for java generics

Tags: java, generics, inheritance, extends

for the following interfaces and classes I have:

```
public interface Animal { //cant change this

public interface AnimalGroup<T extends Animal> { //cant change this

public class DogPack<T extends Animal> implements AnimalGroup<T> { //cant change implements AnimalGroup<T>

public class Dog implements Animal { //can change this
```

this works:

```
    AnimalGroup<Animal> pack;
    pack = new DogPack<Animal>();
```

this does not compile due to type mismatch: cannot convert from DogPack to AnimalGroup

```
    AnimalGroup<Animal> pack;
    pack = new DogPack<Dog>();
```

Can anyone offer any guidance as to why? I can get various combinations to work but not quite sure if the above does not work because Dog does not inherit/extend Animal (it cant)

Thanks

Comment: Generics are *invariant*.  That means the types have to match exactly.  Classes (with polymorphism) are *covariant*.  That means a `Dog` is-a `Animal` and you can use `Dog` where an `Animal` is permitted.  In this case I think you'll need to declare your `AnimalPack` as `<Dog>` because that part has to match. (P.S. when you have problems like this it usually means you're trying to use generics where you should be using regular classes and polymorphism.)

Comment: (In this case I think you should be using either `AnimalPack<Dog>` or you should use `AnimalPack` and `DogPack` without generics, but not trying to use both.  It's redundant at least, and probably wrong design too.)

Comment: You need to use proper formatting and generally pay attention to the instructions. Your generics were getting eaten because you didn't tag them as code.